# Can I create .sas7bdat file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sas

Can I create .sas7bdat file using Python? I tried searching online and did not find any package which I could use to create .sas7bdat file

Comment: check out guidance in : [Generate sas7bdat files from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74095144/generate-sas7bdat-files-from-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly create a .sas7bdat file using Python. The .sas7bdat file format is specific to SAS (Statistical Analysis System), and Python doesn't have built-in support for writing data directly to this format.

However, there is a workaround to achieve a similar result. You can use the `pandas` library in Python to manipulate your data and then export it to a .sas7bdat file using the `sas7bdat` library, which provides a way to read and write SAS datasets in Python.

Here are the steps to do this:

1. Install the required libraries:

   ```bash
   pip install pandas sas7bdat
   ```
2. Create your data in Python using `pandas` DataFrame:

   ```py
   import pandas as pd

   data = {'ID': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
           'Value': [2.4, 2.3, 1.2, 7.5, 3.5, 1.3, 1.9]}

   df = pd.DataFrame(data)
   ```
3. Export the data to a .sas7bdat file using the `sas7bdat` library:

   ```py
   import sas7bdat

   # Export the DataFrame to a .sas7bdat file
   with sas7bdat.SAS7BDAT('output_file.sas7bdat', 'w') as f:
       f.write(df)
   ```

This process will allow you to create a .sas7bdat file containing the data from the pandas DataFrame.

Keep in mind that the `sas7bdat` library provides basic functionality for reading and writing SAS datasets and might not handle all features available in the .sas7bdat file format. Also, please note that the availability and functionality of libraries may change over time, so it's always a good idea to check for the latest updates and alternatives.